# Will data from one PSN transfer to another?

Tags: ps4, destiny, psn

So I have an PSN profile named player1 and if I make another PSN called player2 and play online will the data from player1 transfer to player2?

Comment: Are we talking about save data? Settings? Stats like KDR?

Answer (score 2):

No, PSN users each have different profiles on the PS4, meaning saves are separate.

In the case of Destiny, player profiles are attached to a single PSN account and cannot be transferred to other users.